# Should SQL Server backups be scheduled in SQL Server Agent or as a Scheduled Task?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2

I have inherited a system where a system where our database is backed up by identical scripts, one set up in SQL Server Agent and one set up as a Scheduled Task.

Both are running at the same time, so I'd like to disable one of them.

Apart from my own preferences (I'd leave it as a Scheduled Task), are there other considerations to take into account?